# Retrofit POST request never comes back to OnResponse

Tags: android, api, kotlin, retrofit

I am trying to do a `POST` request with `Retrofit`, which actually works fine, but it never execute `OnResponse` function.
The thing is that with `GET` works fine, but not with `POST` request.

I tried changing the request status code from `201` to `200` but didn't work.
Instead of a `Toast` in `OnResponse` I tried calling another function, tried to associate the body?.it value, etc but nothing of that works, even in debug mode... So I think `OnResponse` is never been executed.
`OnFailure` is never executed too.

Initializer:

```
private val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl("http://myserverurl.com/api/")
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
    .build()
fun orderService    ()  = retrofit.create(OrderService   ::class.java)
```

OrderService.kt

```
interface OrderService {
@POST("pedido")
fun insert(@Body order: OrderEntity, @Header("mykey") myKey:String) : Call<OrderEntity>
}
```

Call:

```
 val call = RetrofitInitializer().orderService().insert(order, mMyKey)
call.enqueue(object : Callback<OrderEntity> {
    override fun onResponse(call: Call<OrderEntity>?,
                            response: Response<OrderEntity>?) {
        response?.body()?.let {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "It works!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }
    override fun onFailure(call: Call<OrderEntity>?, t: Throwable?) {
        Log.e("onFailure error", t?.message)
    }
})
```

So, remembering that the request works, it saves data on the API Server, just does not come back to `OnResponse` so I can't know if it finished already or not in my app.

Comment: Probably a silly question but did you check that `response` or `body` are not `null`? In such a case the application would behave as if `onResponse` was not called (even if it was actually called)

Comment: At least in postman its returning the json of the data I've sent  with code 201. I tried to debug OnResponse but it seams is not reaching there

Comment: Check your logcat when you are making this call ! :)

Comment: Nothing happens in logcat. Its OnFailure is note been executed too. Server is really receiving the info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys. I found the problem. It was returning to OnResponse, but with code 500.
There was a problem with one of the field in my API wich didn't showed up in PostMan..
So thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

have you set okHttp client for HTTP/2 connection?

```
private val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl("http://myserverurl.com/api/")
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
    .client(okhttpClient)
    .build()

private val okhttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it didn't make difference. Works aswell with that code, but I still can't get the response

Comment: Could you share the logcat ?
what is the message in line code here?
Log.e("onFailure error", t?.message)